# An explanation for the form of the spin component operator for a measurement made at an angle in the $x$-$y$ plane

Tags: angular-momentum, operators, quantum-spin

I have three Pauli spin matrices corresponding to the spin states along each Cartesian axis. For some rotation about $\Phi_n$ about the $z$-axis we have:$$S_n=S_xsin(\Theta)cos(\Phi) +S_ysin(\Theta)sin(\Phi)+S_zcos(\Theta)$$ Where $\Theta$ is a rotation about the $z$-axis and $\Phi$ is a rotation about the $z$-axis in the $x$-$y$  plane.  I don't understand how we go from this to the matrix representation:
$$
{S_n=\frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
 cos(\Theta) & sin(\Theta)e^{-i\Phi}\\
sin(\Theta)e^{i\Phi} & -cos(\Theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}}$$
Please can someone explain the origin of the complex exponential terms?

Answer (score 1):

It's just Euler's $\cos \Phi+i\sin \Phi= e^{i\Phi}$ compbined with the usual forms of  Pauli's $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$.